# How to implement drag-down-to-close a React Native Modal?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview, react-native-modal

I'm trying to achieve a feature similar to Tik-Tok's Comments Feature, press a button to open up a modal containing scrollview/flatlist, and we can drag the modal to close itself.

My Goal:

[image]

I did find anything about drag-to-close in React-Native Modal reference, **please help me!**

Code I have now (very basic):

```
    <Modal 
    animationType='slide'
    visible={isOpen}
    transparent
    >
                <View style={{ height: 100, position: 'absolute', bottom: 0 }}>
                    <FlatList .../>
                </View>
    </Modal>
```

Comment: See this third party library it will help you,  https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet

Comment: you can add flatlist in https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-element-dropdown this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great solution provided by @Jatin Bhuva 's comment above, the drag-to-close feature of a modal can be achieved with [React-Native-Bottom-Sheet by @gorhom](https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet)! And in addition, the package allows integrations with flatlists or scrollables inside :)

Answer (score 1):

### In case you're looking for a simple implementation

You can use [PanResponder](https://reactnative.dev/docs/panresponder) and [Animated](https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated) from the standard react-native lib. No need to install new packages, pretty easy to use.

#### Example

Take as an example my recent implementation, it's a generic bottom modal component that closes by swiping to the bottom of the screen:

[image: A gif image from a screen recording that depicts the bottom of an iOS emulator, where a modal is present and it is closed by dragging it down. It shows the clicks of the mouse dragging it down.]

#### Code

```
import { Animated, Dimensions, StyleSheet, PanResponder } from 'react-native';

// ... rest of the code ...

const AnimatedModal: React.FC<AnimatedModalProps> = ({ variant, children }) => {
  // ... rest of the code ...

  const panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
    onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null, { dy: translateY }], { useNativeDriver: false }),
    onPanResponderRelease: (e, gestureState) => {
      if (gestureState.dy > 50) {
        handleAnimationClose();
      } else {
        Animated.spring(translateY, {
          toValue: 0,
          tension: 1,
          friction: 20,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }).start();
      }
    },
  });

  // ... rest of the code ...

  return (
    <Animated.View
      {...panResponder.panHandlers}
      style={[
        styles.container,
        variant === 'bottom' && { transform: [{ translateY }], bottom: 0 },
      ]}>
      {children}
    </Animated.View>
  );
};

// ... rest of the code ...
```